# VBA Excel Value shows as integer while is text

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to do a Vlookup in VBA, and I am getting a

> type mismatch Error 13.

The code is Below:

```
Dim CSVName As String
Dim ThisBook As String
Dim Vlook As Variant

Vlook = Application.VLookup(Workbooks(CSVName).Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A1").Value, Workbooks(ThisBook).Worksheets("Macro").Range("N1:N50").Value, 1, False)
```

When I apply the CSVName Value to the watches window it comes up with Type (Variant/Int) When the file in questions has text in it The cell contains ("BALANCING_SEGMENT"). Which I cannot figure out. What am I missing here? The purpose of this is to check the value in CSVName against the list and return a 1 if its in the list and not if its not, then process an if statement.

Thanks!

Comment: Would help a lot to show all of the relevant code here, including populating the various variables in use.  You have a lot jammed into that one line of code, and you'd find it easier to debug if you declare some worksheet variables and use those in place of the inlined `workbooks(x).worksheets(y)`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have declared and initialized somewhere else a variable named Sheet1, of an integer type or of the string type, you're missing the double quotes around `Sheet1`. The same goes for `ThisBook`.

There's probably a worksheet whose CodeName property is Sheet1 in the workbook where your code resides; the Worksheets() collection expects either an integer index or string identifier, not a Worksheet type, hence the type mismatch error.

If, by using `Workbooks(ThisBook)`, you are trying to refer to the workbook where the code resides, just use `ThisWorkbook` instead.

The final line would then be:

```
Vlook = Application.VLookup(Workbooks(CSVName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("N1:N50").Value, 1, False)
```

If, from the VBE's Properties window, you assign a proper (Name) value to your "Macro" worksheet, such as e.g. MacroWs, you will be able to refer to it directly by this name in your code, provided the code executes within the workbook hosting the worksheet. Then you could go:

```
Vlook = Application.VLookup(Workbooks(CSVName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, MacroWs.Range("N1:N50").Value, 1, False)
```

... and your code would be impervious to the possible renaming of the "Macro" worksheet to something else.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. So the issue was that I did not know the name of  the sheet and it would change per workbook. So I had to add in Activesheet.name and then reference that. The quotations where missing as I was trying to make sure that the first sheet was referenced. Forgot that it wouldn't know which sheet.